# How to filter a Backbone collection on the server

Tags: web-services, backbone.js, collections, filtering

**Is there a common pattern for using [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) with a service that filters a collection on the server?** I haven't been able to find anything in Google and Stack Overflow searches, which is surprising, given the number of Backbone apps in production.

---

Suppose I'm building a new front end for Stack Overflow using Backbone.

On the search screen, I need to pass the following information to the server and get back a page worth of results.

- filter criteria
- sort criteria
- results per page
- page number

Backbone doesn't seem to have much interest in offloading filtering to the server. It expects the server to return the entire list of questions and perform filtering on the client side.

I'm guessing that in order to make this work I need to subclass [Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) and override the [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-112) method so that rather than always GETting data from the same RESTful URL, it passes the above parameters.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Am I missing a feature in Backbone that would make this process simpler or more compatible with existing components? Is there already a well-established pattern to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to pass GET parameters on a request, you should just be able to specify them in the fetch call itself.

```
collection.fetch( {
  data: {
    sortDir: "ASC",
    totalResults: 100
  }
} );
```

The options passed into fetch should directly translate to a [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, and a data property should automatically get parsed. Of course overriding the fetch method is fine too, especially if you want to standardize portions of the logic.

Comment: Is there a way to pass data like this, without doing inside the fetch call? I remember having filter fields like this defined in the collection itself before, but can't remember how I did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, creating your own `Collection` is the way to go, as there are not standards about server pagination except OData.

Instead of overriding 'fetch', what I usually do in these cases is create a `collection.url` property as a function, an return the proper URL based on the collection state.

In order to do pagination, however, the server must return to you the total number of items so you can calculate how many pages based on X items per page. Nowadays some APIs are using things like HAL or HATEOAS, which are basically HTTP response headers. To get that information, I normally add a listener to the `sync` event, which is raised after any AJAX operation. If you need to notify external components (normally the view) of the number of available items/pages, use an event.

Simple example: your server returns `X-ItemTotalCount` in the response headers, and expects parameters `page` and `items` in the request querystring.

```
var PagedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models,options){
    this.listenTo(this, "sync", this._parseHeaders);
    this.currentPage = 0;
    this.pageSize = 10;
    this.itemCount = 0;
  },
  url: function() {
    return this.baseUrl + "?page=" + this.currentPage + "&items=" + this.pageSize;
  },
  _parseHeaders: function(collection,response){
    var totalItems = response.xhr.getResponseHeader("X-ItemTotalCount");
    if(totalItems){
      this.itemCount = parseInt(totalItems);
      //trigger an event with arguments (collection, totalItems)
      this.trigger("pages:itemcount", this, this.itemCount);
    }
  }
});

var PostCollection = PagedCollection.extend({
  baseUrl: "/posts"
});
```

Notice we use another own property, `baseUrl` to simplify extending the PagedCollection. If you need to add your own `initialize`, call the parent's prototype one like this, or you won't parse the headers:

`PagedCollection.protoype.initialize.apply(this,arguments)`

You can even add `fetchNext` and `fetchPrevious` methods to the collection, where you simply modify `this.currentPage` and `fetch`. Remember to add `{reset:true}` as `fetch` options if you want to replace one page with the other instead of appending.

Now if your backend for the project is consistent, any resource that allows pagination on the server may be represented using one PagedCollection-based collection on the client, given the same parameters/responses are used.